# Avoiding multiple lookups in map/unordered_map

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary, stdmap

Let's say we have an expensive function mapping `string` to `int` and want to cache results in a map.

The simplest code would be

```
int mapStringToIntWithCache(std::string const& s) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> cache;
    if (cache.count(s) > 0) return cache[s];
    else return cache[s] = myExpensiveFunction(s);
}
```

But this has 2 lookups.

I therefore tend to write this

```
int mapStringToIntWithCache(std::string const& s) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> cache;
    size_t sizeBefore = cache.size();
    int& val = cache[s];
    if (cache.size() > sizeBefore) val = myExpensiveFunction(s);
    return val;
}
```

This has only one lookup, but seems a little clumsy. Is there a better way?

Comment: doesnt the first snippet need more than two lookups? It has `count` and `cache[s]` twice

Comment: @user463035818 the `count` is the first lookup, followed by one of the two `[s]` lookups, but only ever one of them. So two lookups for each run.

Comment: yeah sure, i didnt read carefully enough. I have to admit that my first reflex was: premature optimization. However, once you already decided to use a cache it isnt premature anymore...

Comment: If you care about performance, do not pass argument by const lvalue reference. This will hinder moving from rvalue `string` arguments if insertion takes place. Use, e.g., perfect forwarding instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `std::map::emplace()` method:

```
int mapStringToIntWithCache(std::string const& s) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> cache;
    auto pair = cache.emplace( s, 0 );
    if( pair.second )
         pair.first->second = myExpensiveFunction(s);
    return pair.first->second;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `try_emplace` if C++17 is available. Which would be better, since `emplace` may copy `s` string argument.

Comment: Assuming it's actually an `int` that's stored, why not `insert`?

Comment: @TheVee `insert` would require to write longer code. Any reason?

Comment: @DanielLangr do not see any difference in this case, if insertion occurs either one will have to copy key, otherwise neither would copy it.

Comment: @Slava I am not sure about this but think that `emplace` may copy key even if insertion doesn't occur. Will check with Standard later, now I am watching Falcon Heavy launch :). Quoting form cpprefernece.com: _"The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately."_

Comment: @Slava You're right, I didn't realize the extra code.

Comment: @Slava You're welcome. Additionally, if OP cares about performance, I would recommend to make `s` parameter a forwarding reference and use `std::forward` within `emplace`. With const lvalue reference, compiler cannot move from `s` during insertion if the argument of `mapStringToIntwithCache` is rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to the @Slava's answer: If you pass argument by const lvalue reference, you cannot move then from this argument if it's rvalue:

```
int i = mapStringToIntWithCache("rvalue argument here");
```

The temporary `std::string` argument will be **copied** here if insertion to `cache` takes place.

You can use *perfect forwarding*, however, if you want to maintain arguments to be of `std::string` type only (e.g., for implicit conversions from string literals), then you need some *wrapper-helper function* solution:

```
template <typename T>
int mapStringToIntWithCacheHelper(T&& s) {
  static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> cache;
  auto pair = cache.emplace( std::forward<T>(s), 0 );
  if( pair.second )
    pair.first->second = myExpensiveFunction(pair.first->first); // can't use s here !!!
  return pair.first->second;
}

int mapStringToIntWithCache(const std::string & s) {
  mapStringToIntWithCacheHelper(s);
}

int mapStringToIntWithCache(std::string && s) {
  mapStringToIntWithCacheHelper(std::move(s));
}
```